# Add text in front of found number, string manipulation

Tags: php

I am parsing big file with a lot of data with php. I got stuck on one case:

If in my string there is a number in curly brackets, I need to add some text first.

**Example**:

```
{4316} Test
```

Should be:

```
{=ATTRVAL("4316")} Test
```

Or in the middle of the string:

```
Some random text {2323} and {3232} I got here.
```

Should be:

```
Some random text {=ATTRVAL("2323")} and {=ATTRVAL("3232")} I got here.
```

I tried so far with a lot of string functions, but no luck at this time.

```
public static function parseStringWithAttributeValue($attributeValue)
{
    preg_match_all('!\d+!', $attributeValue, $matches);

    $string = '';

    foreach ($matches as $match)
    {
       // string .= $match
    }

    return $string;
}
```

I tried first to extract only numbers, and then create the new text, but that is wrong logic. Ideal would be something with preg_replace if it is possible, but I had no luck so far.
I also tried str_replace, but I guess my knowledge only goes this far.
If anyone has idea what approach to take, I would be happy to get any suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
public static function parseStringWithAttributeValue($attributeValue){
    return preg_replace('/{(\d+)}/i', '{=ATTRVAL("$1")}', $attributeValue);
}
```